# SwiftUI: Handling "decodeImageImp failed - NULL _blockArray" Error with AsyncImage and Custom Caching

Tags: swift, xcode, image-processing, caching, swiftui

#### Problem:

I am working on a SwiftUI application where I have implemented a custom asynchronous image loader with caching. However, I'm encountering a warning:

`callDecodeImage:2005: *** ERROR: decodeImageImp failed - NULL _blockArray`

This warning appears when trying to decode and display images fetched from URLs. Let me preface this issue by saying I do not necessarily *see* anything wrong. My images load and seemingly cache correctly. However, I am worried something may not be happening as intended, i.e. I may be wasting memory or whatnot.

Here's the code for my custom CacheAsyncImage view and ImageCache:

#### Code:

```
struct CacheAsyncImage<Content, Content2>: View where Content: View, Content2: View {
    private let url: URL?
    private let scale: CGFloat
    private let transaction: Transaction?
    private let contentPhase: ((AsyncImagePhase) -> Content)?
    private let contentImage: ((Image) -> Content)?
    private let placeholder: (() -> Content2)?
    
    init(url: URL?,
         scale: CGFloat = 1.0,
         transaction: Transaction = Transaction(),
         @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (AsyncImagePhase) -> Content
    ) where Content: View, Content2 == Never {
        self.url = url
        self.scale = scale
        self.transaction = transaction
        self.contentPhase = content
        self.contentImage = nil
        self.placeholder = nil
    }
    
    init(url: URL?,
         scale: CGFloat = 1,
         @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Image) -> Content,
         @ViewBuilder placeholder: @escaping () -> Content2
    ) {
        self.url = url
        self.scale = scale
        self.contentImage = content
        self.placeholder = placeholder
        self.contentPhase = nil
        self.transaction = nil
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        if let cached = ImageCache[url] {
            if contentPhase != nil {
                contentPhase?(.success(cached))
            } else if contentImage != nil {
                contentImage?(cached)
            }
        } else {
            if contentPhase != nil {
                AsyncImage(url: url,
                           scale: scale,
                           transaction: transaction ?? Transaction(),
                           content: { cacheAndRender(phase: $0) })
            } else if contentImage != nil && placeholder != nil {
                AsyncImage(url: url,
                           scale: scale,
                           content: { cacheAndRender(image: $0) },
                           placeholder: placeholder!)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func cacheAndRender(image: Image) -> some View {
        ImageCache[url] = image
        return contentImage?(image)
    }
    
    private func cacheAndRender(phase: AsyncImagePhase) -> some View {
        if case .success (let image) = phase {
            ImageCache[url] = image
        }
        return contentPhase?(phase)
    }
}

fileprivate class ImageCache {
    static private var cache: [URL: Image] = [:]
    static subscript(url: URL?) -> Image? {
        get {
            guard let url else { return nil }
            return ImageCache.cache[url]
        }
        set {
            guard let url else { return }
            ImageCache.cache[url] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

#### Steps I have already taken:

- I verified the URLs to ensure they are valid and pointing to correct image resources.
- I added logging to track the image fetching process but didn't find any clear indicators of the issue's source.
- I considered potential thread safety issues with the caching mechanism but haven't implemented any specific thread-safety measures yet.

I'm open to any suggestions on how to resolve this warning, improve my current implementation, or if there's a better approach to handling asynchronous image loading and caching in SwiftUI.

Comment: I'm experiencing it too with Xcode 15.2. I think there are also frame drops and hangs right before those messages